# Error after posting new data to the web server

Tags: python, django, django-forms

It all looks good by when i try to add some post to my topic I have an error                 created_by=user

: 
[image]

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic


class NewTopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': 5, 'placeholder': 'What is on your mind?'}
        ),
        max_length=40000,
        help_text='The max length of the text is 4000.')

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['subject', 'message']
```

and my view function for this form:

```
def new_topic(request, pk):
board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
user = User.objects.first()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        topic = form.save(commit=False)
        topic.board = board
        topic.starter = user
        topic.save()
        post = Post.objects.create(
            message=form.cleaned_data.get('message'),
            topic=topic,
            created_by=user
        )

        return redirect('board_topics', pk=board.pk)
else:
    form = NewTopicForm()
return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'board': board, 'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='t_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: add your models to the question, specifically the Post model

Comment: adding a models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your Post model

created_by needs to be a Foreign Key to the User table

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

run the following commands after the above changes to reflect the changes in the database

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you so much!